# Which is better approach for OnClick Implementation?

Tags: android, onclick, touch-event, ontouchlistener, onclicklistener

For implementation of onClick function which approach is better?

1. Saving touch start / touch up coordinates and processing this values for closeness? Like, if starting point and up point close each other, let the click action start.
2. Saving touch start / touch up time difference and processing this value? Like, if touch starting time and up time difference less than a value, let the click action start.

And why?

Comment: Just a curiosity. Why not use the built-in?

Comment: Duration and displacement both. Because you might think an accidental swipe, or a long press, as a click.

Comment: The answer of which one better approach is our curiosity. We must say it a little brainstorming :)

Comment: @Singularity, we will check start/up time difference or start/up point coordinate replacements with a static value. The question is which one is better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how many kind of touch events you want to support:

1. on Up : click
2. on Up : without moving much - > click , moved -> swipe
3. on Up : short duration - > click , long duration -> long press has
   been triggered, ignore.
4. on Up and long press triggered :  without moving much - > ignore , moved -> drag n drop

You go into details of duration and displacement , when you really need more kinds of touch events.Best approach depends on scenario. So, if your touchscreen doesn't have a notion of swipe or long press or drag n drop, you might just fire a click on every up event, simplest scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely must implement your own, I would use the option 2.

```
 if(motionEvent==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
    long duration = motionEvent.getDownTime() - .getEventTime();
    if(duration < THRESHOULD)
         click();
 }
```